# Sed command replace number + letter with number + \n + letter

Tags: bash, file, sed

I have a (what I think is a tricky) `sed` problem.

I have a file which contains plain text and numbers.

Every instance in the file, where there is a number `[0-9]` followed by a letter which is either a `C`, `T` or `D`, I would like to replace it with the same number followed by a `\n` character and the same letter.

E.g.

```
551235D 4218789T 435151C
```

I would like to replace with

```
 551235\nD 4218789\nT 435151\nC
```

The problem I am facing is how to replace each letter/number combo with the same letter/number. It is easy to replace `[0-9]` followed by `C`, `T` or `D` with whatever I like, the problem is inserting a `\n` between the number and letter...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/uE6wF1/1)?

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed  's/\([0-9]\)\([DTC]\)/\1\n\2/g' file
```

Use back references.

Comment: Would be worth a mention of `-i` and `-i.bak`. Other than that, looks good.

Comment: @potong Nearly there :D
It's working, outputting what I need to the command line ouput, but when I try to redirect the output to a file like this:
sed  's/\([0-9]\)\([DTC]\)/\1\n\2/g' file > newFile
It doesn't work or give any error messages

Answer (score 0):

In `sed`, a newline can be substituded by escaping it with a `\`:

> [A line can be split by substituting a <newline> into it. The application shall escape the <newline> in the replacement by preceding it by a <backslash>.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html)

Additionally, newlines can easily be added by arguments through multiple uses of `-e`:

> [The commands specified by each -e or -f option shall be added to the script in the order specified. When each addition is made, if the previous addition (if any) was from a -e option, a <newline> shall be inserted before the new addition.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html)

Either of the above can be combined with back-reference substitution (`\1`, `\2`, etc.) to split lines between the desired characters.

```
$ sed 's/\([0-9]\)\([DTC]\)/\1\
> \2/g'
```

or

```
$ sed -e's/\([0-9]\)\([DTC]\)/\1\' -e'\2/g'
```